# Error loading jQuery and CSS

Tags: java, jquery, css

I have a problem when I publish with IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008, I get the following errors:

[image]

This is how I use or charge jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../Scripts/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I already checked my routes and they are fine, and looking in some forums I find myself with some solutions but nothing has worked

Comment: Why do you need to call `jquery` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You said error loading Jquery and CSS, Thats all Jquery theres no CSS in that code, That could be part of the problem, Plus your loading in the Jquery in a very weird way, That could be contributing to the problem.

```
Heres the proper way to load in Jquery: 



<script src="../Scripts/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>




NOTE: All Jquery imports such as this one has to be loaded in inside the <head> tag
```

Comment: Do you have any more code i can see to better understand what might be going on, Or what this website is used for and what your using this code for.